# check_box_tag with label_tag click action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-helpers

```
<%= f.label :category %><br/>
<%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '1', false %>
<%= label_tag 'community', 'community', class: 'category_select', value: '1' %>
<%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '2', false %>
<%= label_tag 'food', 'food', class: 'category_select', value: '2' %>
<%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '3', false %>
<%= label_tag 'music', 'music', class: 'category_select', value: '3' %><br/>
<%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '4', false %>
<%= label_tag 'education', 'education', class: 'category_select', value: '4' %>
<%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '5', false %>
<%= label_tag 'theatre', 'theatre', class: 'category_select', value: '5' %>
<%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '6', false %>
<%= label_tag 'art', 'art', class: 'category_select', value: '6' %><br/>
<%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '7', false %>
<%= label_tag 'culture', 'culture', class: 'category_select', value: '7' %>
<%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '8', false %>
<%= label_tag 'family', 'family', class: 'category_select', value: '8' %>
<%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '9', false %>
<%= label_tag 'sports', 'sports', class: 'category_select', value: '9' %><br/>
```

I'd like to be able to have these options show up in my controller under a `category` array, so I named all the options `category[]`.  What I'd like to accomplish, is for the `label_tag` and `check_box_tag` fields to know about each other:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'community', 'community', false %>
<%= label_tag 'community', 'community', class: 'category_select' %>
```

here, if I click on the words, the box also gets checked.  I tried to accomplish this with the values on the `label_tag`, but it doesn't seem to work.  Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One way to do this is to add the `label` elements in manually (no `erb`), and add the checkboxes and label content as children:

```
<label class="category-select">
  <%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '1', false %>
  Community
</label>
...
```

Although that does change the structure of the html somewhat, and may have an impact on your layout/css.

Comment: this works perfectly... just wanted to throw a heads up to anyone else browsing this =)

Answer (score 16):

You can also pass a block to `label_tag` and then next a checkbox (along with anything else you want) inside the label tag.

```
<%= label_tag do %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'category[]', '1', false %>
  Community
<% end %>
```

Relevant docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-label_tag

Comment: This looks perfect to me.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I'm pretty late to answer this. I was looking solution for same kinda problem and came up with following:

```
<%= label_tag "some_name", raw("#{check_box_tag('some_name')} Click label to check") %>
```

This would create html as follows:

```
<label for="some_name"><input id="some_name" name="some_name" type="checkbox" value="1"> Click label to check</label>
```